# Get each Children element that has a class and insert before its parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am trying to achieve and failing for some reason is..

With this code structure:

```
<div class="catProductAttributeGroup">
  <div class="catProdAttributeTitle">TITLE 1</div>
  Content for class "catProductAttributeGroup" Goes Here </div>
<div class="catProductAttributeGroup">
  <div class="catProdAttributeTitle">TITLE 2</div>
  Content for class "catProductAttributeGroup" Goes Here </div>
<div class="catProductAttributeGroup">
  <div class="catProdAttributeTitle">TITLE 3</div>
  Content for class "catProductAttributeGroup" Goes Here </div>
```

TO DISPLAY LIKE THIS:
I want to make sure theres a title to insertBefore(); that's why I have the first line under the function line.

```
<div class="catProdAttributeTitle">TITLE 1</div>
<div class="catProductAttributeGroup"> Content for  class "catProductAttributeGroup" Goes Here </div>
<div class="catProdAttributeTitle">TITLE 2</div>
<div class="catProductAttributeGroup"> Content for  class "catProductAttributeGroup" Goes Here </div>
<div class="catProdAttributeTitle">TITLE 3</div>
<div class="catProductAttributeGroup"> Content for  class "catProductAttributeGroup" Goes Here </div>
```

USING THIS:

```
$(".catProductAttributeGroup").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find(".catProdAttributeTitle").length > 0) {
        $( ".catProdAttributeTitle").insertBefore($(".catProductAttributeGroup"));
     }
});
```

BUT RENDERING ALL TITLES ON THE TOP OF THE FIRST PARENT LIKE THIS:

```
<div class="catProdAttributeTitle">TITLE 1</div>
<div class="catProdAttributeTitle">TITLE 2</div>
<div class="catProdAttributeTitle">TITLE 3</div>
<div class="catProductAttributeGroup"> Content for  class "catProductAttributeGroup" Goes Here </div>
<div class="catProductAttributeGroup"> Content for  class "catProductAttributeGroup" Goes Here </div>
<div class="catProductAttributeGroup"> Content for  class "catProductAttributeGroup" Goes Here </div>
```

Please somebody help me around this THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(this)` inside the `each` to refer to the current element.

```
$('.catProdAttributeTitle').each(function() {
    $(this).insertBefore($(this).parent());
});
```

If the element is nested, use `closest()` instead of `parent()`.

```
$(this).insertBefore($(this).closest('.catProductAttributeGroup'));
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ogs62fbp/)

Comment: This is a system generated code so i didnt pay attention, My Mistake! I just realised the Tittle Div in wrapped inside of 3 other  Divs like .catProductAttributeGroup>.owl-stage-outer>.owl-stage>**.catProdAttributeTitle** do you think theres another method so far they still stack on top of the first .catProductAttributeGroup

Comment: @Skwashy Yes, use `$(this).insertBefore($(this).closest('.catProductAttributeGroup'));`